# crystal report use Maximum as Sum condition problem

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, max

I met a problem with sum function:
the data have a datetime column and I want to get sum of who's datetime is max. And also there's anoher group condition.
So I do like:

1. Add formula maxDatetime: Maximum({datetime}, {groupcondition})
2. Add new formula for sum ValueToSum: if({datetime} = {@maxDatetime}) then value else 0
3. Sum the value, add new formula totalValue: Sum({@valueToSum}, {groupcondition})

The result is the sum can't be processed, it says: 'valueToSum can't be sumed'.

I think the causor may be using a maximum value as a condition in step 2. Because when use 1 = 1 to replace the condition, there's no problem.

Can anyone give some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually solve such kind of problems by creating additional queries and linking them to main data. Because Crystal Reports does only two passes over data - record reading and aggregate calculation, it can't easily aggregate over already aggregated values.

Another possibility is to accumulate your 'totalvalue' into variable. Something like next may work (needs tweaking probably):

```
WhilePrintingRecords();
NumberVar totalvalue;
If ({datetime} = Maximum({datetime}, {groupcondition})) 
then totalvalue:=totalvalue+value 
else 0
```

This formula (which displays totalvalue) needs to placed into group footer:

```
WhilePrintingRecords();
NumberVar totalvalue
```

Somewhere in group header you need another one to reset totalvalue:

```
WhilePrintingRecords();
NumberVar totalvalue:=0
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Thank you very much! :) And I've finally solve this problem in the first way.

Comment: Awesome advice with the second suggestion (WhilePrintingRecords, etc).  Upvote this guy more often!  I upvoted him from 0 to 1.  He should have more than that. :)